# Drop-down text colour

Tags: android, css, browser, drop-down-menu

Would someone (please) be able to explain how to fix a problem that I have on the Android browser? The drop-down text colour is black on the browser (see attached screenshot, both left and right) but it's fine on Firefox and Safari on my Mac! Any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

The web url is [here](http://www.landedhouses.co.uk/parties-holidays/)

Comment: you locked every thing. i need to inspect element in your site

Comment: f12 developer  tools :)

Comment: Your any time welcome :) I did not seethe effect in android so if you can then please try explore it :)

Comment: I have unlocked the right click too, in case that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Black thing in android might be because there's a custom style sheet that changes `select` tag to black.

Try changing

```
select {
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 20px;
border: 1px solid #444;
padding: 5px;
background: #222;
color: #FFF !important; //here is the change
width: 150px;
```

as there is also a style sheet that has

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: menulist;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
white-space: pre;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
color: black; // this might be causing the problem in some custom style sheet
background-color: white;
cursor: default;
}
```

Now i dont know in which style sheet this is . Find it out :) more over locking right click :)

EDIT ----

Some one added this to your html

```
<style>
label.searchform-label {color: black; }
</style>
```

I dunno where it came from but realized that this is an issue :)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion which unfortunately didn't work. Could you let me know which style sheet contains the second suggestion? I'm not sure! Also, I've unlocked the right click. Thank you for your help!

Comment: check the edit :) some one added `<style>
label.searchform-label {color: black; }
</style>` rather change to `color:white`

Comment: LINE 242 after viewing source

Comment: Hi, thanks but taking that out also makes the 'description' text white. Also, that <style> is not present on other pages where the drop-down text problem still occurs. Hmm.